# DevExpress TileLayoutControl - save and restore Tile's Visibility with XML file

Tags: devexpress, visibility, tile

I use a TileLayoutControl. I use WriteToXML() and ReadFromXML() to save and restore the items position (the items are Tile). I would to be able to save the items Visibility too in the XML file to restore if a Tile is visible or not. How I can do that ?

Thank's for reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save/load custom properties, handle the [LayoutControl.WriteElementToXML](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControl.WriteElementToXML.event) and [LayoutControl.ReadElementFromXML](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControl.ReadElementFromXML.event) events:

```
using DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Native;

void tileLayoutControl1_WriteElementToXML(object sender, LayoutControlWriteElementToXMLEventArgs e) {
    if (typeof(Tile).IsAssignableFrom(e.Element.GetType())) 
        e.Element.WritePropertyToXML(e.Xml, UIElement.VisibilityProperty, "Visibility");
}

void tileLayoutControl1_ReadElementFromXML(object sender, LayoutControlReadElementFromXMLEventArgs e) {
    if (typeof(Tile).IsAssignableFrom(e.Element.GetType())) 
        e.Element.ReadPropertyFromXML(e.Xml, UIElement.VisibilityProperty, "Visibility", typeof(Visibility));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but when i do : 'LayoutControl layoutControl = myTileLayoutControl.GetLayoutControl()' the layoutControl is null. I don't understand why ?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are talking about, because there is no this code snippet in the solution I have provided...

Comment: I will to explain more. I used a TileLayoutControl. I used WriteToXml, for example to save the position of the Tile. I searched to add the Visibilty too. I found out the snippet that you shown in your answer. But i don't find `tileLayoutControl1_WriteElementToXML(object sender, LayoutControlWriteElementToXMLEventArgs e)` I see this in the control LayoutControl and I try to have it with `LayoutControl layoutControl = myTileLayoutControl.GetLayoutControl()` but layoutControl is null and I can't use the methods that you talking about. Sorry if I'm not clear, I wiil post to you a snippet quickly.

Comment: hmm... it looks like these events are absent at the TileLayoutControl level, sorry. Could you please contact with DevExpress team in order to move these events onto the LayoutControlBase level where the WriteToXML/ReadFromXml methods are? The current situation looks unexpected to me(wrong design?).